Equivalence of inverse transformations under distributional equivalence
Consider continuous, invertible transformations $g,h : \Bbb{R}^d \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^d$ and suppose $g(Y) \overset{d}{=} h(Y)$, where $Y$ is a $N(0, I)$ random variable. Then what can we infer about the transformations $g(\cdot)$ and $h(\cdot)$?
The motivation comes from the one dimensional case, in which we can conclude that either $g^{-1} = h^{-1}$ or $g^{-1} = -h^{-1}$. Essentially, distributional equivalence implies equivalence of the inverse maps. I wanted to know whether something similar exists in the general case. Of course, I don't expect such a "neat" result in higher dimensions due to the spherical symmetry of the standard multivariate gaussian distribution, but anything along these lines would be appreciated.
I am also curious towards the possibility of extending this for a more general class of distributions.
Edit: The question reduces to the following. If $f: \Bbb{R}^d \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^d$ is a continuous, invertible transformation such that $Y \overset{d}{=} f(Y)$, where $Y \sim N(0, I)$, then is it necessary for $f$ to be a rotation, i.e., $f(x) = Rx$ for some orthogonal matrix $R$?

Since the unit standard multivariate normal $\mathcal{N}(0, I)$ is rotationally symmetric, let $R$ be any orthogonal matrix, that is, $R^TR = R R^T =I$, then also $RY \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$. Since $g$ and $h$ are invertible
$$
   g(Y) \stackrel{D}{=} h(Y) \stackrel{D}{=} h(RY) ~\text{using the inverse} \\ 
   Y \stackrel{D}{=} g^{-1}h(RY) 
$$
so if $g^{-1}h$ is a rotation, we are done, sine product of rotations is a rotation.
This is consistent with what you quote for the one-dimensional case, since the only rotations then are $\pm 1$.

Hi Kjetil, thanks for your response. I wanted to point out a couple of things. I do not understand the use of the orthogonal matrix $R$ in your argument. By taking the inverse, we have $Y \overset{d}{=}  g^{-1}h (Y)$, and so $g^{-1}h$ being a rotation would be a sufficent criteria.  Secondly, although this is a sufficient condition, I was actually looking for necessary conditions. That is, are rotations the only transformations for which a standard gaussian is mapped to a standard gaussian?

Fast answer: are rotations the only transformations for which a standard gaussian is mapped to a standard gaussian? You could ask that as a separate question, if you restrict to continuous functions, I guess yes ... but allowing discontinuous functions there must be many other possibilities (in the one-dim case, bin the x-axes and shuffle)

Normal distribution would be invariant under anything that maps $x^2\to x^2$. So the full class of transformations is the orthogonal group which includes rotations as well as reflections.

Although this answer correctly finds a condition, it does not tackle the harder part of the question, which is to show that this is the only possible relationship between $g$ and $h.$  BTW, $-1$ is not considered a "rotation" in $\mathbb R^1:$ it is a reflection because it reverses orientation.
